# Enviando parâmetro body via fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, handlebars.js, fetch

Estou tentando enviar uma solicitação de forma assíncrona via javascript para o backend em node, segue o código do front:

```
if ( window.location.pathname.indexOf('/') != - 1 || window.location.pathname.indexOf('/auth/authenticate') != - 1 ){
    let bntSend = document.querySelector('#sendInfo');
    bntSend.addEventListener('click', async (ev) => {
        let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
        let passwd = document.querySelector('#passwd').value
        console.log(email.toString(), passwd.toString());

            await fetch('/auth/authenticate', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email, 
                    passwd
                })
            })
            .then((data) => { 
               console.log(data);
            }) 
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    });

}
```

O Backend:

```
router.post('/authenticate', async function(req, res) {
const { email, passwd } = req.body; 
try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+passwd');

    if(passwd !== await user.passwd){
        let message = "Senha incorreta, tente Novamente!";
        return res.render(path.resolve('../frontend/views/layouts/admin/login'), {message})
    } 

    user.passwd = undefined;

    return res
    .send({
        status: 200, 
        data:{
            user, 
            passwdResetToken:generateToken({ id: user._id })
        },
    })  
} catch (err) {

    let message = 'Email ou senha inválidos, tente novamente!';
    return res.render(path.resolve('../frontend/views/layouts/admin/login'), {message})
}
});
```

Meu problema acontece quando envio a requisição pelo front, o body retorna null. Mas quando envio pelo Insomnia/Postman, funciona perfeitamente.

Erro no node:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'passwd' of null
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro, dá para supor que o erro esteja nesse trecho:

```
passwd !== await user.passwd
```

Primeiro que utilizar `await` não faz sentido nenhum, mas isso não irá causar um erro, o problema é que o valor de `user` é igual a `null`, e acessar uma propriedade qualquer de `null` lança uma exceção.

Mas por que pelo Postman funciona?

Outra suposição: é possível que o seu back-end não esteja conseguindo decodificar a mensagem que você está enviando pelo `fetch`, e como resultado `email` fica com o valor `undefined`, e por isso você não consegue encontrar o `user` no seu banco de dados.

Normalmente, numa requisição `HTTP`, nós enviamos um `header` para informar o servidor o tipo de codificação estamos utilizando na carga útil da requisição. Algumas bibliotecas como `Axios` e `jQuery`, e também o `Postman` adicionam esse header automaticamente, mas o `fetch` não faz isso.

Então tente informar o seu servidor qual é o tipo de codificação de sua requisição, adicione o header dessa forma:

```
fetch('/auth/authenticate', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, passwd })
})
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que faltava, muito obrigado. E o async que falou tava ali por engano, eu tinha testado pra ver se mudava algo mas esqueci de tirar depois haha